# Allow inline tag editing when viewing question lists

Tags: feature-request, tags, inline-tag-editor

@Jeff recently [announced](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/04/new-10k-feature-inline-tagging/) that the inline tagging editor used by mods is now available to 10K users.  This is a really great feature, IMO, especially since I'm not forced to add a comment to the retagging.  It would improve on its awesomeness if it were available when viewing lists of questions as well as when editing questions.

While, in most cases, actually viewing the full question is necessary to properly tag a question, when updating many questions to simply retag them, doing so on the question list would be a vast improvement.  Likewise when you see a clearly incorrect tag in the listing and simply want to correct it, for example, changing `drag and drop` to `drag-and-drop`.  Viewing the full question just to make such a change is inconvenient, especially when making several changes based on a list of questions filtered by tag.

Comment: +1 - make it easier for those of us who want to help to help!

Comment: See my answer here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45407/quick-retagging-love-it-hate-it/45423#45423

Comment: @JonSeigel post deleted?